# The word break rule file

Tags: java, icu

IBM has apparently open-sourced their ICU source code for Unicode and Globalization support, part of which is a text boundary locator for detecting where breaks can be located in text.

However, the break detection stuff relies on rules and I cannot locate the rules files anywhere.

Where can I get the word break rules text files for `com.ibm.icu.text.BreakIterator` and `com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedBreakIterator`?

Comment: huh? you lost me there. How about a little background on what this is, maybe put in relevant tags?

Comment: This is not a real question. Well, it is, but it really needs more background so we know what it is that you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.icu-project.org/ holds all the source code for icu4j which IBM has released under an open source license. This includes the boundary analysis stuff like dictionary- and rule-based break iterators.

However, there doesn't appear to be a text file suitable for perusing. I not sure that IBM would have released their rule set as open source (since it's a pretty big technological advantage to them). Instead, the idea is to create your own rule set, a tutorial of which is [here](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2008/05/tokenizing-text-with-icu4js.html).

That same tutorial states that you can dump the default rules by running:

```
RuleBasedBreakIterator rbbi = (RuleBasedBreakIterator)
    BreakIterator.getWordInstance(Locale.getDefault());
String defaultRules = rbbi.toString();
```